# How can I find out if a column is unused powershell

Tags: document-library, powershell, content-type

I have noticed in some of my document libraries that I have a column that is unused. Is there a bit of code in powershell that will tell me which document libraries have the column in question but it is unused. So I want a list of all the document libraries that have the column `marking` but its not assigned to a content type thus is unused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be a little bit tricky because you can define columns on a list basis only. If you are looking for web site columns they have a property which is called used in [Used In Web Content Typ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.usedinwebcontenttypes%28v=office.15%29.aspx).

If it isn't used in a web content type then it is likely that this column isn't used anywhere in the site collection.

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like:

```
$webs = get-spsite "your site" | get-spweb

foreach ($myWeb in $webs) {
   foreach ($listEle in $myWeb.lists) {
       foreach ($ctype in $listEle.ContentTypes) {
           if($ctype.Name -eq "") {
              write-host $listEle.Name }
        }
   }
}
```

This will parse your web collection for lists with empty content types.  You might also have to put "Null" for $ctype.Name part, not sure.  Not %100 sure what empty content types are typed as.